# Usage of "-Ay" "-cy" options in vgcreate

Tags: linux, lvm

What do the options "-Ay" "-cy" in the vgcreate command do? I checked the man page but was unable to find them.

for example:

```
vgcreate -Ay -cy cluster_vg /dev/vdb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `vgcreate(8)` man page:

> ```
>   -c, --clustered {y|n}
>           If  clustered  locking is enabled, this defaults to y indicating
>           that this Volume Group is shared with other nodes in  the  clus‐
>           ter.
>
>           If  the  new Volume Group contains only local disks that are not
>           visible on the other nodes, you must specify --clustered n.   If
>           the  cluster  infrastructure is unavailable on a particular node
>           at a particular time, you may still be able to use  such  Volume
>           Groups.
> ```

From the `lvm(8)` man page:

> ```
>    -A, --autobackup {y|n}
>           Whether or not to metadata should  be  backed  up  automatically
>           after  a  change.  You are strongly advised not to disable this!
>           See vgcfgbackup(8).
> ```